How to reorganize data to correctly lineplot in Python
I have the following code that plots ydata vs xdata which is supposed to be a circle. The plot has two subplots -- a lineplot with markers and a scatter plot.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


xdata = [-1.9987069285852805, -1.955030386765729, -1.955030386765729, -1.8259096357678795, -1.8259096357678795, -1.6169878720004491, -1.6169878720004491, -1.3373959790579202, -1.3373959790579202, -0.9993534642926399, -0.9993534642926399, -0.6176344077078071, -0.6176344077078071, -0.20892176376743077, -0.20892176376743077, 0.20892176376743032, 0.20892176376743032, 0.6176344077078065, 0.6176344077078065, 0.999353464292642, 0.999353464292642, 1.3373959790579217, 1.3373959790579217, 1.6169878720004487, 1.6169878720004487, 1.8259096357678786, 1.8259096357678786, 1.9550303867657255, 1.9550303867657255, 1.9987069285852832]
 
ydata = (0.0, -0.038801795445724575, 0.038801795445724575, -0.07590776623879933, 0.07590776623879933, -0.10969620340136318, 0.10969620340136318, -0.13869039009450249, 0.13869039009450249, -0.16162314123018345, 0.16162314123018345, -0.1774921855402276, 0.1774921855402276, -0.18560396964016201, 0.18560396964016201, -0.185603969640162, 0.185603969640162, -0.17749218554022747, 0.17749218554022747, -0.16162314123018337, 0.16162314123018337, -0.13869039009450224, 0.13869039009450224, -0.10969620340136294, 0.10969620340136294, -0.0759077662387991, 0.0759077662387991, -0.038801795445725006, 0.038801795445725006, 0.0)



fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(16,6))
fig.suptitle('Plot comparison: line vs scatter'+ 3*'\n')
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=1, hspace=3)
fig.supxlabel('x')
fig.supylabel('y')


ax1.plot(xdata, ydata, 'o-', c='blue')
ax1.set_title('Line-point plot', c='blue')

for i in range(len(xdata)):
   ax2.scatter(xdata, ydata, c='orange')
   ax2.set_title('Scatter plot', c='orange')
plt.savefig('line_vs_scatter_plot.png')
plt.show()

Output:

From the output, it can be seen that the lineplot does not connect the dots (or points). Can we rearrange the x or y data in someway that fixes the issue? Or do something else?

You can start with one point and sort them by distance as you successively add points, but that will be pretty slow. If this is a one-off thing and you don't have to do it for many points then that should be fine. How were the points generated?

The points were generated by solving a complex matrix equation (eigenvalue problem).

If the xy coordinates have a consistent zig-zag pattern (odd/even), you could do :
def unzigzag(data):
    data = list(data) # just in case
    return data[::2] + data[::-2] + [data[0]]

ax1.plot(*map(unzigzag, [xdata, ydata]), "bo-")

NB: This plot is annotated with the physical position (starting from 1) of x/y in their lists.

If not, one option would be to use shapely :
from shapely import MultiPoint
from shapely.geometry.polygon import orient

def unzigzag(x, y, ori=-1): # -1: clock-wise
    p = MultiPoint(list(zip(x, y))).convex_hull
    return list(orient(p, ori).boundary.coords)

ax2.plot(*zip(*unzigzag(xdata, ydata)), "-bo") # the ori has no effect

Animation to highlight the orientation :


Thanks. The second answer works. The first answer gives the following error:
return data[1::2] + data[-2::-2] + [data[1]]            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~ TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple. Btw what does the line imply? Arrange all the odd items clockwise first, then append the even ones anti-clockwise and then add the first odd item again to complete the circle?

You can add data = list(data) just to make sure we have lists before the concatenation (see update). And regarding your question, yes, that's the idea of the first approach/unzigzag.

Thanks, I figured out that my xdata is a list while my ydata is a tuple. Hence the concatenate throws an error due to this mismatch. I got the idea -- if we split into even and odd sector, we can avoid the connection between two consecutive points in the original ordering. However, why clockwise and anti-clockwise splitting as well?

Nice graphs and explanation @Timeless ;)

Ah! I see now. Since both go clockwise, the connection doesn't lose consistency. Still, there are some doubts: (1) Where's data[0]? I think data[-2::-2] starts from data[28] and ends at data[0]. If I'm correct, your second arrow needs to start from index 28, not 30. There's no index 30 at all if you follow the Python-based indexing. (2) Isn't data[1] an overlap of two points (same point plotted twice)?

@hbaromega, you were right to insist, fixed ;). For the indices in the plot, i'm using 1-indexing.

@Timeless, thanks for the update. Could you update your arrows on the graph accordingly, just to keep it consistent with Python's indexing in the code?

You can sort the point clockwise, here is an implementation. In your case you would have to zip the x and y lists:
origin = [0, 0]
refvec = [0, 1]

x2, y2 = zip(*sorted(zip(xdata, ydata), key=clockwiseangle_and_distance))

plt.plot(x2, y2, 'o-', c='blue')

Output:

clockwiseangle_and_distance function by @MSeifert
import math

def clockwiseangle_and_distance(point):
    # Vector between point and the origin: v = p - o
    vector = [point[0]-origin[0], point[1]-origin[1]]
    # Length of vector: ||v||
    lenvector = math.hypot(vector[0], vector[1])
    # If length is zero there is no angle
    if lenvector == 0:
        return -math.pi, 0
    # Normalize vector: v/||v||
    normalized = [vector[0]/lenvector, vector[1]/lenvector]
    dotprod  = normalized[0]*refvec[0] + normalized[1]*refvec[1]     # x1*x2 + y1*y2
    diffprod = refvec[1]*normalized[0] - refvec[0]*normalized[1]     # x1*y2 - y1*x2
    angle = math.atan2(diffprod, dotprod)
    # Negative angles represent counter-clockwise angles so we need to subtract them 
    # from 2*pi (360 degrees)
    if angle < 0:
        return 2*math.pi+angle, lenvector
    # I return first the angle because that's the primary sorting criterium
    # but if two vectors have the same angle then the shorter distance should come first.
    return angle, lenvector

